# reference array in another array loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to use the items of one array within a for loop that is looping through another array. For example, I want to display the item name (an array that already exists) when asking for the price of each of these items. "What price is *item[i]*". I don't think you can use item[i] in this instance. I've also tried using a get method and using a counter variable, but I must be doing something wrong.

The readPrice portion isn't working - specifically the item[i]. Does anyone have a suggestion how to accomplish the same thing without using item[i]?

I'm new to java, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious answer, but I would really appreciate the help!

Here is my code:

```
private String[] items;
private int[] priority;    
private double[] price;

public void readInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You will need to enter seven shopping items.");

    items = new String[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an item: ");
        items[i] = keyboard.nextLine();   
    }

}

**public void readPrice()**
{
    price = new double[7];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < price.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the price for " + **items[i]**);
        price[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();

    }

}
```

Comment: Very basic stuff, just look up how to pass parameters to a method, or find a book on java programming. Please don't come to stack overflow before first doing a minimal amount of research yourself.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `item[i]`?  And why do you believe that "I don't think you can use item[i] in this instance"?

Comment: Where are you calling `readPrice()`?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well here's the answer for you. There are two main approaches to this: either pass the object `items` as a parameter, or make it global.

**Global Variable Approach**

For the global approach, which you seem to sort of already be doing, first declare your object as a field for your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private String[] items = new String[7];

    //...Rest of class goes here
}
```

Now you can access it from your two methods as you wish.

```
public readInput()
{
    // Add stuff to items
    items[0] = "hi";
}
public readPrice()
{
    // Read from items
    System.out.println(items[0]);
}
```

**Method Parameter Approach**

Now if you want to actually pass an object from one method to another but don't want it to be accessible to any other methods, you can make it a parameter like this:

```
public readPrice(String[] items)
{
    // Read from items
    System.out.println(items[0]);
}
```

And then you can call the method from somewhere else passing specific instances of the object type.

```
public inputPrice()
{
    String[] items = new String[7];
    // Add stuff to items
    items[0] = "hi";
    this.readPrice(items);
}
```

Passing parameters is especially useful if you want to call a single method several times, but have it act on different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a class Item.

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double price;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" + "name=" + name + ", price=" + price + '}';
    }

}
```

After create an object of class Item

```
    public class TestPaper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item;
        Item[] itemTable = new Item[7];
        ArrayList<Item> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            item = new Item();
            //set value
            item.setName("item1");
            item.setPrice(200);
            //store the object to a table or an arraylist
            itemTable[i] = item;
            itemlist.add(item);
        }

        for (Item temp : itemTable) {
            System.out.println(temp.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

This is better solution, but I will answer you with your code.

You have 7 items, so  you can print the items like this:

```
private String[] items;
private int[] priority;    
private double[] price;

public void readInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You will need to enter seven shopping items.");

    items = new String[7];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an item: ");
        items[i] = keyboard.nextLine();   
    }

}

**public void readPrice()**
{
    price = new double[7];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i = 0; i < price.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the price for " + **items[i]**);
        price[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();

    }

    public void printdata(){
    for(int I=0; I<7; I++){
       System.out.println("item name: " +item[i] +" price: "+price[i])

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a stacktrace of the occurring error to make everyone happy. I personally would create a Map to assign a price to an item.

**Code**

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Items {

    private int itemsLength = 10;
    private Map<String, Double> items = new HashMap<>();

    public Items() {
        System.out.println("Please fill in the details below: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String itemName;
            Double price;
            System.out.println("Enter an item name: ");
            itemName = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(String.format("Enter %s's price: ", itemName));
            price = in.nextDouble();
            items.put(itemName, price);
        }
        System.out.println("Here are your items: ");
        System.out.println("+------------------------+");
        System.out.println(String.format("|%-10s | %-10s %-6s", "Item", "Price", "|"));
        for (Entry<String, Double> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("|%-10s | %-10s %-6s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), "|"));
        }
        System.out.println("+------------------------+");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Please fill in the details below: 
Enter an item name: 
Shoes
Enter Shoes's price: 
20
Enter an item name: 
Shirt
Enter Shirt's price: 
20
Enter an item name: 
Necklace
Enter Necklace's price: 
50
Enter an item name: 
Bracelet
Enter Bracelet's price: 
30
Enter an item name: 
Socks
Enter Socks's price: 
5
Enter an item name: 
Flip-flops
Enter Flip-flops's price: 
10
Enter an item name: 
Soda
Enter Soda's price: 
2
Enter an item name: 
Diamonds
Enter Diamonds's price: 
20000
Enter an item name: 
Weird Item
Enter Weird Item's price: 
99999
Enter an item name: 
Another Weird Item
Enter Another Weird Item's price: 
99999
Here are your items: 
+------------------------+
|Item       | Price      |     
|Necklace   | 50.0       |     
|Another Weird Item | 99999.0    |     
|Shirt      | 20.0       |     
|Bracelet   | 30.0       |     
|Diamonds   | 20000.0    |     
|Weird Item | 99999.0    |     
|Shoes      | 20.0       |     
|Socks      | 5.0        |     
|Soda       | 2.0        |     
|Flip-flops | 10.0       |     
+------------------------+
```

P.S: This is my first response, sorry if its not pretty

**Edit**: If you want to keep the order when outputting then construct a TreeMap instead of a HashMap.